# How to change tabs in the unit test of a component that uses Angular Material Tabs

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-material, karma-jasmine

I have a `LoginView` component in which I have Angular Material Tabs. In one tab there's a `LoginForm` component displayed and in a second tab there's a `RegistrationForm` component.

What I try to test in `LoginView` is that when I click on a second tab, a `RegistrationForm` would be displayed. However, I have no idea how to click a tab. I've tried adding `name` or `id` to mat-tab but it isn't being generated in DOM, `querySelectorAll()` also returns `null`.

Source:

```
<mat-tab-group dynamicHeight class="py-5">
  <mat-tab label="{{'form.letsLogIn' | translate}}">
    <app-login-form></app-login-form>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="{{'form.letsRegister' | translate}}">
      <app-registration-form></app-registration-form>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Spec file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { LoginViewComponent } from './login-view.component';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@Component({selector: 'app-login-form', template: ''})
class LoginFormStubComponent {}

@Component({selector: 'app-registration-form', template: ''})
class RegistrationFormStubComponent {}

describe('LoginViewComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginViewComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginViewComponent>;
  let compiled: any;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ 
        LoginViewComponent,
        LoginFormStubComponent,
        RegistrationFormStubComponent ],
      imports: [
        TranslateModule.forRoot(),
        MatTabsModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginViewComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    compiled = fixture.nativeElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should have a title', () => {
    expect(compiled.querySelector('h1')).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should display login form at start', () => {
    expect(compiled.querySelector('app-login-form')).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should display registration form after clicking second tab', () => {
    compiled = fixture.nativeElement;
    compiled.querySelectorAll('mat-tab')[1].click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(compiled.querySelector('app-registration-form')).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Please add all the spec file. The BeforeEach is essential to help you.

Comment: @JFPicard I've edited my code.

Answer (score 9):

I just worked the same problem.
Your test is fine. Just add async() and use whenStable().

```
it('should display registration form after clicking second tab', async(() => {
  compiled = fixture.nativeElement;
  compiled.querySelectorAll('mat-tab')[1].click();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    expect(compiled.querySelector('app-registration-form')).toBeTruthy();
  });
}));
```

Answer (score 6):

The `mat-tab` element is just the container. The element that handles the click uses the class `mat-tab-label`. Try:

```
fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.mat-tab-label'))[1].nativeElement.click();
```

EDIT:

Alternatively, include inside your component a reference to the `MatTabGroup` component, and then set `MatTabGroup.selectedIndex` directly or from a component function:

Component HTML:

```
<mat-tab-group dynamicHeight class="py-5" #tabGroup=="matTabGroup">
...
```

Component TS:

```
@ViewChild('tabGroup') tabGroup: MatTabGroup;

setTab(index: number) {
    // maybe add some bounds and null checking
    this.tabGroup.selectedIndex = index;
}
```

Unit test usage:

```
component.setTab(1):
fixture.detectChanges();
```

Comment: still the same, returns null

Comment: Strange. That works for me (mat-tab doesn't). It might be easier to include a reference to the `MatTabGroup` in your component, and set `MatTabGroup.selectedIndex` directly (or via a component function).

Comment: it still doesn't work, hovewer, I think it's becase of Material animation - until the animation of changing tab is not finished, it shows selectedIndex to the old tab. So the question is how can I wait for animation end in unit tests? I've tried some `wait` or `sleep` which I know from Protractor, but couldn't find it for Karma.

Comment: I've used `setTimeout();` and it works, but I believe, there must be a better way to wait for animation end.

Comment: Look into fakeAsync and tick or fixture.whenStable().

Comment: You can subscribe to matTabGroup.animationDone as well

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work. Use MatTabHarness for changing index of the mat tab. Don't forget to use async-await.

```js
let loader: HarnessLoader;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>

describe('test scenerio', ()=>{
  
  beforeEach( async()=>{
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [MyModule], 
      declarations: [MyComponent]
    }).compileComponents();
    
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent)
    loader = TestbedHarnessEnvironment.loader(fixture)
  })

  
  if('test case', ()=>{
    let matTab = await loader.getHarness(MatTabGroupHarness);
    await matTab.select({label: 'myLabel'})
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

adding up to above ans by  G. Tranter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52448061/5558536)

```
it('tab change', () => {
    component.onTabChanged(1);
    fixture.detectChanges();
})
```

'tab change' is the attribute I was missing

Comment: Why do you prefer this approach over the approaches proposed in the previous answers? Does this take advantage of new capabilities? Are there particular scenarios where this is more appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

HTML:

```
<mat-tab-group #tabGroup
```

TS:

```
@ViewChild('tabGroup') tabGroup: MatTabGroup;

goToTab(index: number): void {
    this.tabGroup.selectedIndex = index;
}
```

test.spec.ts

```
it('should change tab', () => {
    fixture.debugElement.componentInstance.goToTab(1);

    fixture.detectChanges();

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        // tab is now visible. expects go here
    });
});
```